I am not able to configure Grafana connectivity
I am trying to connect to Grafana configuration for Amazon Timestream I keep getting this error.
RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 54.239.32.126:443: i/o timeout
I have attached the policy and permission needed but to no avail
